# Depth image based rendering and ATW technique from Oculus

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, 3d, virtual-reality

What I have is a 2D rgb image and its depth image(256 gray degrees).
I want to derive a new image, just like I look the scene with depth from a different 3D point of view.

The target effect is like ATW(Asynchronous Time Warping) in the field of VR.
I have tried relief mapping,3D warping equotation. But the efficiency of algorithm is quite low, far from the demand of Real-Time.

I guess the time Oculus's algorithm spends is within 5ms, and the algorithm shouldn't be too complex. How can I realize this?Thx.

At last, forgive my poor English :)

Youtube link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvtEXMlQQtI

Comment: This is the ATW introduction from Oculus:https://developer.oculus.com/blog/asynchronous-timewarp-examined/